# Powershell: Output an array item to Rich textbox

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to write a version of Cards Against IT and have a question.

I have an array from which I am using `Get-Random`. My first thought was to have the white and czar cards both on one script. but I would need to use items= list of cards then use the for-each item in items function. If I had both types of  cards in a list I would assume the script would not work with 2 "list" cmdlets. Can I rename these to "cards" and "czar"

this an example of the white cards in a array I believe.

also when I run this script instead of only one item in the list getting returned all of them do. How could I fix this? Any direction is always appreciated.

```
#Generated Form Function
function GenerateForm {
########################################################################
# Generated On: 8/29/2016 1:53 PM
# Generated By: christnerw
########################################################################

#region Import the Assemblies
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-   Null
#endregion

#region Generated Form Objects
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$richTextBox9 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$card = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$richTextBox8 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox7 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox6 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$Czar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$richTextBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#----------------------------------------------
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#----------------------------------------------
#Provide Custom Code for events specified in PrimalForms.
$handler_richTextBox7_TextChanged= 
{
#TODO: Place custom script here

}

$handler_form1_Load= 
{
#TODO: Place custom script here

}

$card_OnClick= {
$richTextBox2.Text = $white
}

$card_OnClick= {
$richTextBox3.Text = $white
}

$card_OnClick= {
$richTextBox4.Text = $white
}

$card_OnClick= {
$richTextBox5.Text = $white
}

$card_OnClick= {
$richTextBox6.Text = $white
}

$card_OnClick= {
$richTextBox7.Text = $white
}

$card_OnClick= {
$richTextBox8.Text = $white
}

$card_OnClick= {
$richTextBox9.Text = $white |Out-String
}

{
}



$handler_richTextBox5_TextChanged= 
{
#TODO: Place custom script here

}
$handler_Czar_Click= {
$richTextBox1.Text = $czar |Out-String
}

{


}

$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{#Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form   issue
$form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$form1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,139,0,0)
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 808
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 1306
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$form1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans   Serif",12,1,3,1)
$form1.Icon =         [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon('C:\Users\christnerw\Desktop\Powers      hell Project\flat_icons-graficheria.ico')
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.Text = "Cards Aghinst IT"
$form1.add_Load($handler_form1_Load)

$richTextBox9.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$richTextBox9.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox9.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox9.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans  Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 992
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 532
$richTextBox9.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox9.Name = "richTextBox9"
$richTextBox9.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 283
$richTextBox9.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox9.TabIndex = 12
$richTextBox9.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox9)


$card.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$card.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",12,1,3,1)

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 1062
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 198
$card.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$card.Name = "card"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 51
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 189
$card.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$card.TabIndex = 10
$card.Text = "Click for White Card"
$card.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$card.add_Click($card_OnClick)

$form1.Controls.Add($card)

$richTextBox8.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$richTextBox8.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox8.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox8.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans  Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 686
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 532
$richTextBox8.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox8.Name = "richTextBox8"
$richTextBox8.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 283
$richTextBox8.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox8.TabIndex = 8
$richTextBox8.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox8)

$richTextBox7.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$richTextBox7.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox7.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox7.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 365
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 532
$richTextBox7.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox7.Name = "richTextBox7"
$richTextBox7.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 297
$richTextBox7.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox7.TabIndex = 7
$richTextBox7.Text = ""
$richTextBox7.add_TextChanged($handler_richTextBox7_TextChanged)

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox7)

$richTextBox6.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$richTextBox6.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox6.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox6.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 60
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 532
$richTextBox6.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox6.Name = "richTextBox6"
$richTextBox6.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 283
$richTextBox6.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox6.TabIndex = 6
$richTextBox6.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox6)

$richTextBox5.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$richTextBox5.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox5.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox5.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 60
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 274
$richTextBox5.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox5.Name = "richTextBox5"
$richTextBox5.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 283
$richTextBox5.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox5.TabIndex = 5
$richTextBox5.Text = ""
$richTextBox5.add_TextChanged($handler_richTextBox5_TextChanged)

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox5)

$richTextBox4.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$richTextBox4.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox4.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox4.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 992
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 274
$richTextBox4.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox4.Name = "richTextBox4"
$richTextBox4.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 283
$richTextBox4.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox4.TabIndex = 4
$richTextBox4.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox4)

$richTextBox3.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox3.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 686
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 274
$richTextBox3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox3.Name = "richTextBox3"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 283
$richTextBox3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox3.TabIndex = 3
$richTextBox3.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox3)


$Czar.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$Czar.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",12,1,3,1)

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 199
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 28
$Czar.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$Czar.Name = "Czar"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 68
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 135
$Czar.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$Czar.TabIndex = 2
$Czar.Text = "Click for Czar  Card"
$Czar.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$Czar.add_Click($handler_Czar_Click)

$form1.Controls.Add($Czar)

$richTextBox2.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$richTextBox2.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox2.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 365
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 274
$richTextBox2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox2.Name = "richTextBox2"
$richTextBox2.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 297
$richTextBox2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox2.TabIndex = 1
$richTextBox2.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox2)

$richTextBox1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,0,0,0)
$richTextBox1.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$richTextBox1.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 391
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 28
$richTextBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1"
$richTextBox1.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 221
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 490
$richTextBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0
$richTextBox1.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox1)

#endregion Generated Form Code

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function

#Call the Function
GenerateForm

# Cards
########################################################################################
  $white = 
  "Rotating the Backup Tapes" ,
  "a PEBCAK" ,
  "rm -rf /*.*" ,
  "a faulty crossover cable" ,
  "a KVM with a broken M" ,
  "a one button mouse" ,
  "a laser pointer" ,
  "scanning a little too much with nmap" ,
  "a coffee stained mousepad" ,
  "a webcam pointed at the coffee maker" ,
  "a bastion host" ,
  "a salvaged motherboard with a parallel port" ,
  "a razorsharp punchdown tool" ,
  "my rooted phone" ,
  "a mouse connected serial -> ps/2 -> usb" ,
  "0118 999 881 999 119 725...3" ,
  "my password" ,
  "a fingerprint scanner" ,
  "a scanning electron microscope" ,
  "a helpdesk ticket to 'fix the cpu'" ,
  "a hard drive degaussing machine" ,
  "a multitool with a bottle opener" ,
  "a larger database connection pool" ,
  "a rainbow pack of 3.5 floppy disks" ,
  "a usb stick found in the parking lot" ,
  "an Arduino runnning NetBSD" ,
  "a shell script written in BASIC" ,
  "Edward Snowden" ,
  "CryptoLocker" ,
  "a serial port mouse" ,
  "5000 free AOL CDs" ,
  "Angelina Jolie in Hackers" ,
  "an RJ-45 crimping tool" ,
  "Clippy" ,
  "Two Factor Auth" ,
  "Have you tried turning it off and on again" ,
  "a flaky VPN connection" ,
  "script kiddies" ,
  "an IP Webcam with a default password" ,
  "rebuilding a RAID array" ,
  "manually fixing 10/100/1000 'auto' negotiation" ,
  "viewing web filter block logs" ,
  "the server is down" ,
  "pinging 127.0.0.1" ,
  "Using hillary clinton's private email server"

  ##################################################################################################

  $czar = 
  "The new IT Director has a sick tattoo of ____________",
  "The last consultant was fired over ____________",
  "In a pinch, ____________ can be used to remote reboot a server",
  "____________ is Layer 8 of the OSI networking model",
  "Forgetting ____________ in the datacenter is a firing offense",
  "We're going to use ____________ instead of updating to IPv6",
  "____________ is the last stage of our ____________ rollout (Pick 2)",
  "That red plunger switch on the wall launches ____________",
  "I got this coffee mug from a conference about ____________ back in 1997",
  "Had a user fall prey to a sophisticated ____________ phishing attack",
  "Two factor auth with ____________ and ____________ (Pick 2)",
  "Forgot my badge this morning and had to use ____________ to get in",
  "____________ is now included for free with every OS Update",
  "____________ is now required every time you restart ____________ (Pick 2)",
  "The hot new videogame this year is ____________ Simulator!",
  "A helpdesk call to fix ____________ with ____________ (Pick 2)",
  "I just got a new certification in ____________"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, some changes had to be made.

You had a space in between `Out-` and `null` when adding types at the top of your script which caused an error, so delete the space.

Second change, you can't use the name `$czar` to reference both the button you click for a czar card, and also the list of possible values for the czar cards, so I renamed the list of cards to `$czarValues`.

Next, you need to define the cards at the top of the script, rather than at the end, or else you'll have an error the first time the script is loaded which was happening to me, so I moved the card definitions from the end to the top.

Finally, since we changed the name of the card array to `$czarValues` you also need to change the value of the Add_Click handler as well, so change this:

```
$handler_Czar_Click= {
$richTextBox1.Text =  $czar | Get-Random | Out-String
}
```

to this:

```
$handler_Czar_Click= {
$richTextBox1.Text =  $czarValues | Get-Random | Out-String
}
```

One more thing, how to populate values in your white cards.

```
$card_OnClick= {
$richTextBox2,$richTextBox3,$richTextBox4,$richTextBox5,$richTextBox6,$richTextBox7,$richTextBox8,$richTextBox9 | % {$_.Text = $white | Get-Random }
}
```

With all of these changes, the game now mostly works, as seen here:

[image]

The finished code with the changes I made.

```
    #
# Cards
########################################################################################
  $white = 
  "Rotating the Backup Tapes" ,
  "a PEBCAK" ,
  "rm -rf /*.*" ,
  "a faulty crossover cable" ,
  "a KVM with a broken M" ,
  "a one button mouse" ,
  "a laser pointer" ,
  "scanning a little too much with nmap" ,
  "a coffee stained mousepad" ,
  "a webcam pointed at the coffee maker" ,
  "a bastion host" ,
  "a salvaged motherboard with a parallel port" ,
  "a razorsharp punchdown tool" ,
  "my rooted phone" ,
  "a mouse connected serial -> ps/2 -> usb" ,
  "0118 999 881 999 119 725...3" ,
  "my password" ,
  "a fingerprint scanner" ,
  "a scanning electron microscope" ,
  "a helpdesk ticket to 'fix the cpu'" ,
  "a hard drive degaussing machine" ,
  "a multitool with a bottle opener" ,
  "a larger database connection pool" ,
  "a rainbow pack of 3.5 floppy disks" ,
  "a usb stick found in the parking lot" ,
  "an Arduino runnning NetBSD" ,
  "a shell script written in BASIC" ,
  "Edward Snowden" ,
  "CryptoLocker" ,
  "a serial port mouse" ,
  "5000 free AOL CDs" ,
  "Angelina Jolie in Hackers" ,
  "an RJ-45 crimping tool" ,
  "Clippy" ,
  "Two Factor Auth" ,
  "Have you tried turning it off and on again" ,
  "a flaky VPN connection" ,
  "script kiddies" ,
  "an IP Webcam with a default password" ,
  "rebuilding a RAID array" ,
  "manually fixing 10/100/1000 'auto' negotiation" ,
  "viewing web filter block logs" ,
  "the server is down" ,
  "pinging 127.0.0.1" ,
  "Using hillary clinton's private email server"

  ##################################################################################################

  $czarValues = 
  "The new IT Director has a sick tattoo of ____________",
  "The last consultant was fired over ____________",
  "In a pinch, ____________ can be used to remote reboot a server",
  "____________ is Layer 8 of the OSI networking model",
  "Forgetting ____________ in the datacenter is a firing offense",
  "We're going to use ____________ instead of updating to IPv6",
  "____________ is the last stage of our ____________ rollout (Pick 2)",
  "That red plunger switch on the wall launches ____________",
  "I got this coffee mug from a conference about ____________ back in 1997",
  "Had a user fall prey to a sophisticated ____________ phishing attack",
  "Two factor auth with ____________ and ____________ (Pick 2)",
  "Forgot my badge this morning and had to use ____________ to get in",
  "____________ is now included for free with every OS Update",
  "____________ is now required every time you restart ____________ (Pick 2)",
  "The hot new videogame this year is ____________ Simulator!",
  "A helpdesk call to fix ____________ with ____________ (Pick 2)",
  "I just got a new certification in ____________"


#Generated Form Function
function GenerateForm {
########################################################################
# Generated On: 8/29/2016 1:53 PM
# Generated By: christnerw
########################################################################

#region Import the Assemblies
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
#endregion

#region Generated Form Objects
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$richTextBox9 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$card = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$richTextBox8 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox7 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox6 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$Czar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$richTextBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#----------------------------------------------
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#----------------------------------------------
#Provide Custom Code for events specified in PrimalForms.
$handler_richTextBox7_TextChanged= 
{
#TODO: Place custom script here

}

$handler_form1_Load= 
{
#TODO: Place custom script here

}



$card_OnClick= {
$richTextBox2,$richTextBox3,$richTextBox4,$richTextBox5,$richTextBox6,$richTextBox7,$richTextBox8,$richTextBox9 | % {$_.Text = $white | Get-Random }
}


$handler_richTextBox5_TextChanged= 
{
#TODO: Place custom script here

}
$handler_Czar_Click= {
$richTextBox1.Text =  $czarValues | Get-Random | Out-String
}

{


}

$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{#Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form   issue
$form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$form1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,139,0,0)
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 808
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 1306
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$form1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans   Serif",12,1,3,1)
#$form1.Icon =         [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon('C:\Users\christnerw\Desktop\Powers      hell Project\flat_icons-graficheria.ico')
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.Text = "Cards Aghinst IT"
$form1.add_Load($handler_form1_Load)

$richTextBox9.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$richTextBox9.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox9.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox9.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans  Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 992
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 532
$richTextBox9.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox9.Name = "richTextBox9"
$richTextBox9.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 283
$richTextBox9.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox9.TabIndex = 12
$richTextBox9.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox9)


$card.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$card.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",12,1,3,1)

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 1062
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 198
$card.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$card.Name = "card"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 51
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 189
$card.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$card.TabIndex = 10
$card.Text = "Click for White Card"
$card.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$card.add_Click($card_OnClick)

$form1.Controls.Add($card)

$richTextBox8.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$richTextBox8.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox8.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox8.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans  Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 686
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 532
$richTextBox8.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox8.Name = "richTextBox8"
$richTextBox8.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 283
$richTextBox8.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox8.TabIndex = 8
$richTextBox8.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox8)

$richTextBox7.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$richTextBox7.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox7.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox7.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 365
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 532
$richTextBox7.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox7.Name = "richTextBox7"
$richTextBox7.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 297
$richTextBox7.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox7.TabIndex = 7
$richTextBox7.Text = ""
$richTextBox7.add_TextChanged($handler_richTextBox7_TextChanged)

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox7)

$richTextBox6.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$richTextBox6.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox6.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox6.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 60
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 532
$richTextBox6.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox6.Name = "richTextBox6"
$richTextBox6.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 283
$richTextBox6.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox6.TabIndex = 6
$richTextBox6.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox6)

$richTextBox5.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$richTextBox5.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox5.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox5.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 60
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 274
$richTextBox5.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox5.Name = "richTextBox5"
$richTextBox5.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 283
$richTextBox5.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox5.TabIndex = 5
$richTextBox5.Text = ""
$richTextBox5.add_TextChanged($handler_richTextBox5_TextChanged)

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox5)

$richTextBox4.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$richTextBox4.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox4.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox4.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 992
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 274
$richTextBox4.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox4.Name = "richTextBox4"
$richTextBox4.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 283
$richTextBox4.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox4.TabIndex = 4
$richTextBox4.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox4)

$richTextBox3.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox3.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 686
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 274
$richTextBox3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox3.Name = "richTextBox3"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 283
$richTextBox3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox3.TabIndex = 3
$richTextBox3.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox3)


$Czar.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$Czar.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",12,1,3,1)

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 199
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 28
$Czar.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$Czar.Name = "Czar"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 68
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 135
$Czar.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$Czar.TabIndex = 2
$Czar.Text = "Click for Czar  Card"
$Czar.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$Czar.add_Click($handler_Czar_Click)

$form1.Controls.Add($Czar)

$richTextBox2.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$richTextBox2.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox2.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 365
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 274
$richTextBox2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox2.Name = "richTextBox2"
$richTextBox2.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 223
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 297
$richTextBox2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox2.TabIndex = 1
$richTextBox2.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox2)

$richTextBox1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,0,0,0)
$richTextBox1.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$richTextBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8.25,1,3,1)
$richTextBox1.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 391
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 28
$richTextBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1"
$richTextBox1.ReadOnly = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 221
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 490
$richTextBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0
$richTextBox1.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox1)

#endregion Generated Form Code

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function

#Call the Function
GenerateForm
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now if I can figure out how to get a single random string from the white cards to all my rich text box's  should be all set.

Comment: Added how to do that to my answer above.

Comment: I see it now Thanks!